# Create scheduled job and run the periodically

Tags: python, flask

I have flask web service application with some daily, weekly and monthly events I want to store these events and calculate their start time, for example for an order with count of two and weekly period.
The first payment is today and other one is next week.

I want to store repeated times and then for each of them send notification on the start time periodically.

What is the best solution ?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried or any resources that you would described? This question feels rather vague

Comment: I have two solution in my mind first of all using background job and run them with cron and the other using a task queue like celery, but I don't know what is the best way and standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used windows task scheduler to schedule a .bat file. The .bat file contained some short code to run the python script.

This way the scripy is not idling in the background when you are not using it.
As for storing data in between, I would save it to a file.